# Auth0 Custom Social Connection To Google OAuth2 - Invalid Scope

Tags: auth0, google-identity, auth0-connection, auth0-actions

When setting up a custom social connection in Auth0 I run into an error where Google OAuth2 responds with:

> You are receiving this error either because your input OAuth2 scope name is invalid or it refers to a newer scope that is outside the domain of this legacy API. This API was built at a time when the scope name format was not yet standardized.

I have setup my custom oauth social connection with the following:

1. /authorize endpoint: **https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth**
   2 ./token endpoint: **https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token**
2. Scope: **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile**
3. Google Client Id and Secret
4. Updated the connection through Auth0 Management with this these configs:

```
{
  "options": {
    "authorizationURL": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
    "client_id": "{google-client-id}.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "{google-client-secret}",
    "customHeaders": {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "redirect_uri": "https://{tenant}.us.auth0.com/login/callback",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "tokenURL": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "upstream_params": {
      "access_type": { "value": "offline" },
      "include_granted_scopes": { "value": "true" },
      "prompt":{ "value": "consent" }
    },
    "useOauthSpecScope": false
  },
  "is_domain_connection": false,
  "enabled_clients": [
    "{enabled_client_id}"
  ]
}
```

Order of Testing Events:

1. Google presents profile selection screen (good)
2. I select a profile
3. My redirect in the Google Client: https://{tenant}.us.auth0.com/login/callback
4. Auth0 displays error screen indicated the above message

A few things I noticed:

1. When using prebuilt google-oauth2 connection in Auth0 they escape spaces between scopes with a (`+`) not `%20`
2. When observing the custom social connector generated url they escape scope spaces with `%20`
3. When attempting to overwrite scope values by using `upstream_params` google throws an error when using the `+` instead of `%20`

Before you ask, I am trying to setup multiple google clients (1 per application) within a tenant, based on assignment. If its possible to use the custom OAuth2 strategy to achieve this I would like to.

Comment: Figured it out. Wrote a [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@BlueUmbrellaSoftware/auth0-multi-tenancy-and-social-identity-210b9676389e) about how I solved it.